# Please don't inbox notify me that I asked a question

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, moderators, global-inbox, per-site-meta

I love the new moderator feature that alerts us of new questions on the Meta site we belong to. I always keep on top of the Gaming Meta while I'm online, but this does a lot to either speed up my notice, or give me an alert that something happened overnight.

It also warns me that I've asked a question. Which is less than useful. Is it possible to have the inbox not send a notification to me if I am the author of the new Meta question?

Comment: What about the times you forget you've asked a question?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Yeah, that's sane.

We'll stop notifying moderators of their own meta questions after the next deploy.