# Comment on an edit

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, comments, edits

I would like to be able to make comments on edits. I imagine this could be implemented by addressing an `@`-comment to any of the editors of a post. So if user X has edited a post, and I write a comment starting with `@X`, that user gets notified.

This would be useful for discussing edits or providing feedback.

Examples:

- I would often like to tell people that edit posts to not just edit the obvious formatting errors, but also the spelling and grammar or other language and formatting errors.
- Just to say thanks to someone who added useful information to an answer of mine.

Comment: *blush* I searched but did not find.

Comment: 1 minute, 59 seconds from `feature-request` to `status-completed`.  (ok, so it was already implemented, but still...)

Comment: @AdamDavis: I couldn't resist :)

Comment: @AdamDavis [My personal record is 7 minutes](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/posts/48243/revisions "Shame the image is broken"), as far as *actual* completions go. That's for a `bug`, though. For `feature-request`, I've got [19 minutes](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/90180/please-dont-inbox-notify-me-that-i-asked-a-question). ♪

Comment: possible duplicate of [Allow post editor to see @comments directed at him](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/36052/allow-post-editor-to-see-comments-directed-at-him)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The syntax already works. Have you tried it yet?

That said, I've found that most users don't respond to my comments on their edits (probably because they had no reason to). Guess the lack of feedback does make it unclear if it really works :)