# What's the difference between "bookmarking" and "following" a post?

Tags: support, bookmarks, faq-proposed, follow-post

Now that [following posts](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/345661/the-follow-questions-and-answers-feature-is-now-live-across-the-network) (see also the [prior announcement](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/345148/upcoming-feature-follow-questions)) is possible, I feel like this needs a canonical answer:

**Question**: What's the difference between "bookmarking" (formerly "favoriting") and "following"?

Thus far, I noticed that following applies to answers (as well as questions), prompts inbox notifications, and is not displayed to other users.  There's probably several other aspects I'm unaware of, e.g., badges.

Answer (score 33):

#### Bookmarking

- Only works on questions, not on answers
- Is publicly visible (including in SEDE)
- Generates badges: [Favorite Question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/help/badges/33/favorite-question) and [Stellar Question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/help/badges/34/stellar-question)
- A list of your bookmarked questions across the network is available [in your network profile](https://stackexchange.com/users/current?tab=favorites)
- Does not generate inbox notifications, but the tab on your profile page contains a badge with the number of updates
- Edits and new answers count as updates; comments do not
- It's possible to search for questions favorited by a user with the `inbookmarks:<userid>` or `inbookmarks:mine` operator

#### Following

- Works on questions and answers
- Is not publicly visible
- Does not generate badges
- Generates inbox notifications
- Edits, new answers, and comments count as updates
- It will be possible to filter question lists to show only those you're following

Comment: (It seems it is not possible to "follow" one's own posts [or maybe it's more accurate to say you follow them automatically], while it is possible to bookmark them.)